# CSS Grid column min-content does not fit the content

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-grid, responsive-images

I'm trying to use a CSS Grid layout do display some contents with a responsive image. 
The image with the attributes `srcset` and `sizes` works like a charm.

Using the example of the snippet below, when viewport has 600px wide (DPR=1), the browser loads the image with 300x300px and renders it with 250px wide. I expect the first column (named illustration) to fit the size of the image on the screen (250px).

This works as expected on Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge. The problem is that on Firefox first always gets the natural width of the image inside (300px in this case) and it gets worst when DPR increases.

To reproduce the problem, just open this question on different browsers. In Firefox you will see the red background of the first column.

**Am I missing something?**

If I set the width of the image with CSS it works fine but I'm trying to avoid this to allow the image sizes to be set dynamically (in a CMS for instance).

```css
.content {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: min-content auto;
  grid-template-areas: "illustration description" "illustration links";
}

.illustration {
  grid-area: illustration;
  background-color: red;
}

.description {
  grid-area: description;
}

.links {
  grid-area: links;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="illustration">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50" srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/900x900 900w, https://via.placeholder.com/450x450 450w, https://via.placeholder.com/300x300 300w" sizes="(min-width: 900px) 300px, (min-width: 600px) 250px, (min-width: 490px) 250px, 100px"
    />
  </div>
  <div class="description">Bla bla bla</div>
  <div class="links">Link 1, Link 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/a8hdvdwz/3/

Comment: Thanks for the comment.
Won't that ignore the size defined by the `sizes` attribute?